# Can I make bigger my rib cage doing breathing squats, pullover etc.?

Tags: muscle-gain, chest

I wanna make my rib cage bigger for better chest size. I've heard that breathing squats, pullover, traction raider (it's like pullover without weight [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpDVkHFhx1M)(video on russian)) could help me get bigger chest.

I've tried this over a month ago. My program looks like this: squats with breathing pause(1 rep 1 deep inhale and exhale after each 5 reps I increase number of inhale and exhale by 1. And doing 25-30 reps in 1 set. 5-6 sets). I'm doing squats and light pullover like superset. Then I perform superset with pullups and flat bench press(wide grip). At the end of workout I normally do traction raider. And after all these I feel real discomfort at the center of my chest.

Maybe anybody tried this too? Can this help me get bigger chest?

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2lohbT3guo) that I've watched

Answer (score 2):

Arnold Schwarzeneggar talked about this in his book "the encyclopedia of modern bodybuilding", even the updated version. He says a lot of bodybuilders say you cant expand your ribcage but he had luck doing pullovers to expand his ribcage. This all being said...

If you search online you'll find that the ribcage doesnt expand because it is bone, and you cant make bones bigger. When you are young and developing, you can increase the density of your bones, technically making your rib cage bigger.

What a pullover actually does is help build intercostal muscles between ribs which give you an appearance of a bigger rib cage. Other exercises like the breathing exercises you are doing should help, but these are tiny muscles so don't expect to look like you have barrels for a chest anytime soon. Working these out though will help you look better bodybuilding wise though.